# Extrapolating a fitted curve- Methods

Tags: curve-fitting, extrapolation

I would like to extrapolate different curves I've fitted to my dataset (just two variables).

However, apart from the constant, linear, polynomial (so it basically includes the linear approach), and rational function extrapolation, I don't know what methods I could use.

So, are there any other methods I could use for this?
From my search, I couldn't find (or maybe I just didn't understand) anything useful.

Comment: What programming language or software package would you prefer to use?

Comment: Well, if I could, I'd say R.